# Get id using angular from HAL representation

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hal

How can i get any object id from Hal representation?

Exactly i want to get this from specific user from allUser list. There is example:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "users" : [ {
      "login" : "user1",
      "firstName" : "Bolek",
      "lastName" : "Kowal",
      "email" : null,
      "password" : null,
      "gender" : null,
      "birthDate" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/games-organizer/api/users/1"
        },
        "user" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/games-organizer/api/users/1"
        },
        "roles" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/games-organizer/api/users/1/roles"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "login" : "user2",
      "firstName" : "Lolek",
      "lastName" : "Kowalski",
      "email" : null,
      "password" : null,
      "gender" : null,
      "birthDate" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/games-organizer/api/users/2"
        },
        "user" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/games-organizer/api/users/2"
        },
        "roles" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/games-organizer/api/users/2/roles"
        }
      }
    }
```

Eventually how can i delete specific user using rest spring api and angular/spring? I don't know how can i do this without having id from any user(object).

Update:

I want to use this id, in invoke some method like this:

```
$scope.$on('deleteUser', function (event, id) {
        userService.delete({id: id}).$promise.then(
            function () {
                // Broadcast the event to refresh the grid.
                $rootScope.$broadcast('refreshUserGrid');
                // Broadcast the event to display a delete message.
                $rootScope.$broadcast('userDeleted');
                $scope.clearForm();
            },
            function () {
                // Broadcast the event for a server error.
                $rootScope.$broadcast('error');
            });

    });
```

I want to delete some record from database in springRestAPI.

Comment: not having id from any user means?

Comment: It means i don't know how i can get id from any users in that representation. Should i use links in any ways?

Comment: if yo know which user you wan to delete then whats the issue?

Comment: It's the issue, i can select any user from list, but i don't know how to get his id. It's the issue -> id from user in that representation.

Comment: @smok010 Use hal resources links and not id fields. So lets suppose you  get provided json  from server. Then you decided to delete entity, you just pass single user json to your `userService` and inside the `userService` you could navigate to the resource url like `resource._links.self.href` Another option is to construct the url manual in your `userService` if you actually have only user id for some reason and not the whole resource.  But then again if you have user id, you can easily get the resource from your server and back to option one

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to delete details of user2 then you can do this :

```
  For (var i=0;i<allUser.users.length;i++){
   if(allUser.users[i].login=="user2"){
         allUser.users.splice(i-1,i);
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's not exactly what i mean. I updated my answer. I want id to use it in my service method to remove record from database. Not only from this list.